# import of redux results in undefined

Tags: reactjs, webpack, redux, babeljs

I'm having weird errors.

When i try to import redux like this:

```
import Redux from 'redux'
```

And when i try to console it

```
console.log('Redux is', Redux);
```

It gives me Redux is undefined.

I'm using webpack with babel loader, all standard configurations, nothing seems wrong. I also yarn removed all modules and re-added them, still got the same thing. Now my index.js is just simple as below:

```
import Redux from 'redux';
console.log('Redux is ', Redux);
```

My webpack config is like below: '

```
module.exports = {
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  entry: ['./src/index.jsx', 'babel-polyfill'],
  output: {
      path: path.resolve('dist'),
      filename: 'bundle.js',
      publicPath: '/',
  },
  resolve: {
     extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
  },
  module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.jsx?$/,
            use: {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
          },
          include: __dirname,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
        }
      ],
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },
  plugins: [HtmlWebpackPluginConfig],
};
```

And i'm using yarn. below is my package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "redux": "^3.7.2"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-core": "^6.25.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.29.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "webpack": "^3.4.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.6.1"
},
```

If i switch to use CDN by adding script tag on index.html, it works fine.

=========EDIT========

as Gilad's answer, doing it this way works

```
import { createStore } from redux;
// do stuff with createStore
```

But why I can't do it this way:

```
import Redux from 'redux';
const { createStore } = Redux;
```

The latter one gives me "Cannot read property 'createStore' of undefined"

=========MORE EDIT========

i just had a look at the source code of redux, it is written in typescript and there is no "export default" or "export as namespace", that is probably why I can't use

```
import Redux from 'redux';
const { createStore } = Redux;
```

Correct me if im wrong.

Please help.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your configurations is fine.

Instead of using `import Redux from 'redux'`, and the for example using `Redux.createSore`, you can use: `import { createStore } from 'redux'` and then call `createStore` directly.

The same goes off course for `combineReducers` and any other function redux exposes.

Comment: thanks for your quick reply Gilad. Your solution did work fine. i just updated my question, why i can't achieve the same using the second way as shown above?

Comment: You're correct, it is because redux has no default export